# this List<string> ListName as a parameter?

Tags: c#, list, this

What does it mean when you have a this List as a parameter to a method?

```
public static void KillZombies(this List<Zombie> ZombiesToKill, int NumberOfBullets)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can't find it, but I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would mean that the method is an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

The code calling the method might look a little confusing:

```
var zombies = new List<Zombie>();
zombies.KillZombies(15);
```

In reality, this is a kind of syntactic sugar which is equivalent to:

```
public static void KillZombies(List<Zombie> zombiesToKill,
                               int numberOfBullets)
{
    // Code here
}
```

With the calling code looking like:

```
var zombies = new List<Zombie>();
KillZombies(zombies, 15);
```

Comment: It looks like when KillZombies is called, only NumberOfBullets is passed.  Where is ZombiesToKill typically defined if it's not sent as a parameter?  I apologize for the lack of code, if this is impossible to answer without any context, I understand.

Comment: @Soo - I just updated my answer to hopefully explain why you're seeing what you are.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

In this case, extending `List<Zombie>`. You would call it like this:

```
listOfZombies.KillZombies(numberOfBullets);
```

Where the type of `listOfZombies` is `List<Zombie>` and `numberOfBullets` is an integer.

Comment: ...you passed me, but I'm making a come-back! :-P

Comment: @Justin Niessner - Hehehe... the race is on :)